# Mysql Innodb: Combining 3 Tables Into Single Table for Quick Search... Conditional Joins

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb, composite-key

BACKGROUND:

I am developing a search feature that enables users to search three entities at once: classes, student organizations, and events by name.

MySQL 5.6 and Innodb will be utilized on a relatively small server.

TABLES:

Search

```
entity_id  (tiny_int)
entity_type  (tiny_int)
full_name   (varchar(255))

Index (Primary) -> entity_id, entity_type
Index (FULL TEXT INDEX) -> full_name
```

Class (entity_type = 1)

```
class_id
ALL OTHER COLUMNS...
```

Events (entity_type = 2)

```
event_id
ALL OTHER COLUMNS
```

Orgs (entity_type = 3)

```
org_id
ALL OTHER COLUMNS
```

QUESTION:

Is it appropriate to index the name of 3 seemingly similar but different data sets (class, event, organization) into one search table through the use of `entity_id, entity_type` Primary Key?

How would I go about doing a join on the search table with the `Class, Events, Orgs` tables? Is there a conditional I can do using the `entity_type`?

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a reasonable approach to linking these three table types. It's v similar to what you often see ppl do with 'account_type: user, admin, other' and links to separate settings for each.

To do a join between the main table and all three subs will depend on how similar the columns are. If they are v similar you could do three joins in the same query and put the `entity_type` as part of the on clause. If they are v different then you may be better served by splitting up the query into 3 distinct joins. You could union these together but it may or may not be worth it.

Comment: Can an "ON" statement have multiple conditions such as `ON a.entity_id = b.entity_id AND a.entity_type = 1` ?